# Use float as default in Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, parameters, floating-point, double

I'm justing looking for a way so that i don't have to add 'f' to all my doubles, when programming: e.g.:

```
FunctionTakingLotsOfFloatsAsParameter( 1.1f , 2.2f , 3.3f , 4.4 );
```

I want to be able to write this instead:

```
FunctionTakingLotsOfFloatsAsParameter( 1.1 , 2.2 , 3.3 , 4.4 );
```

Is there a way to make the compiler creating a float instead of a double as standard non-integer 
numbers?

Comment: Why would you want to? `double` can have more than enough rounding errors, so why use `float` which only saves you 4 bytes at best. `float` is only provided for legacy support IMHO.

Comment: I think you should mark this method which takes parameters as double.

Comment: If you really want to you can modify the javac source. Should not be too much work , you only have to swap the detection of double and float tokens somewhere.

Comment: @josefx This should be on a list of famous last words. :)

Comment: yeah, I might refrain from doing that ;)

Comment: @biziclop for openjdk it would be in sun.tools.java.Scanner.scanReal(), changing the default of isSingleFloat and setting it false on 'd'. Even if nothing else relies on the source (which it should not) it is more of an exercise and not something I would do myself in a production environment^^.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. It's fixed in the [language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.2).

Mind you, it's a good thing it is, it would be one hell of a debug session to find the cause of the sudden precision loss in some builds, compared to the same code built with a different compiler.

One of the basic tenets of Java is that (unlike in C) the language should be as completely specified as possible. You might argue that they sacrificed ease of use here and there but in most cases the value of such a thorough specification is well worth the slight inconvenience it might cause.

Answer (score 4):

Nope.. Do you have a specific reason to use floats in the first place? Doubles are more precise and the memory overhead should IMO be insignificant to justify use of plain floats..

Comment: Most libraries which is associated with graphics seem to use floats, and since i program python half of the time I always forget the f on all my numbers.

Comment: Hmm ok, maybe Eclipse quick fix can be of use to ease the pain a bit.. Especially with 3D it probably is a good idea to be reminded that you are in fact dealing with less precision than double.